# CodingBat Warm up 2 Python last2

Tags: python

I think I have the solution to this problem but when I run it on pythonfiddle.com or Canopy nothing comes up.

The problem is:

> Given a string, return the count of the number of times that a
>   substring length 2 appears in the string and also as the last 2 chars
>   of the string, so "hixxxhi" yields 1 (we won't count the end
>   substring).
>
> ```
> last2('hixxhi') → 1
> last2('xaxxaxaxx') → 1
> last2('axxxaaxx') → 2
> ```

My solution is :

```
def last2(str):
    test2 = str[-2:]
    start = 0
    count = 0
    while True:
        if str.find(test2, start, -2) > 0:
            count +=1
            start = str.find(test2, start, -2) + 1
        else:
            break   
    return count
```

When I call the function `last2`, I get nothing. Is there something I'm missing?

Comment: Not on point since there are already good answers, but avoid using a built in function name like str as a variable, as you could cause unexpected behavior.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`str.find()` returns `-1` if a match is not found. If the match is found at the *start* of the string, `0` is returned, but your test condition excludes this case.

```
if str.find(test2, start, -1) > 0:
```

You want to match `0` too:

```
if str.find(test2, start, -2) >= 0:
```

You could avoid using `str.find()` twice here, and you want to allow for the *one but last* character to count too (`xxxx` has `xx` in there twice outside of matching the last two characters). Last but not least, if the string is shorter than length three, there never will be any matches:

```
def last2(value):
    if len(value) < 3:
        return 0
    test2 = value[-2:]
    start = 0
    count = 0
    while True:
        index = value.find(test2, start, -1)
        if index == -1:
            break
        count +=1
        start = index + 1
    return count
```

I've avoided shadowing the built-in `str()` function here too.

Demo:

```
>>> last2('hixxhi')
1
>>> last2('xaxxaxaxx')
1
>>> last2('axxxaaxx')
2
```

Comment: I thought his problem was that he got no output? so he should put in a print statement?

Comment: @M4rtini: the code posted *always* returns a value. That means the OP either didn't formulate the question very well or didn't post the actual code they used..

Comment: The function would return the value, but without a print statement he would not see it? Or does pythonfiddle\canopy send every function return value to stdout?

Comment: @M4rtini: codingbat solutions ask only for the function.

Comment: Sounded like he was trying to run his code elsewhere to test the output. "When I call the function last2, I get nothing" to mee this sounds like the problem was not about algoritmh, but that he was not seeing any output. I might be wrong tho :P

Comment: @M4rtini: You may have a point there, but until the OP adds a clarification, all we can do is speculate. In any case, the code posted passes [the exercise on Codingbat](http://codingbat.com/prob/p145834).

Comment: My problem is that I got no output when I ran the code in Pythonfiddle or canopy when I usually do. Thank You for all the commnets. And Martijn was right about the situations where my solution would not provide the right answer. So thank you

Comment: @Manny_G: Right, outside of an interactive interpreter, you need to add `print` statements to produce output.

Answer (score 0):

You've got an off by one error. `str.find` returns -1 if the string does not contain the substring, but it will return 0 if the substring is at the beginning of the string. Notice that your method works fine on the third example.

It should be:

```
if str.find(test2, start -2) >= 0:
```